# Can not call Web action URL in Openwhisk

Tags: api, openwhisk

I setup a serverless Openwhisk.
I want to training with Web Actions and REST API call.
I created a file called hello.js, created a package where my web action can live, enabled my action to be a web action (refer https://horeaporutiu.github.io/blog/openwhisk-web-actions-and-rest-api-calls/). But I can't finding my Web Action URL (with curl and go to my URL).

```
ubuntu@Openwhisk:~$ wsk package create demo1 -i
ok: created package demo1
ubuntu@Openwhisk:~$ wsk action create demo1/hello hello.js --web true -i
ok: created action demo1/hello

ubuntu@Openwhisk:~$ wsk list -i
Entities in namespace: default
packages
/guest/demo1                                                           private
actions
/guest/demo1/hello                                                     private nodejs:6
triggers
rules

ubuntu@Openwhisk:~$ curl localhost:9001/api/v1/web/guest/demo/hello
{"status":404,"message":"Error: Not found."}
```

Please help to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that's the wrong port. What does `wsk action get ping --url` give? On my system, the non-ssl controller can be found on port 10001, but I use SSL on port 443, with `curl -k`.